# Как спланировать web приложение

Tags: php, javascript, html5

По ходу развития проекта встала проблема масштабируемости. Один сервер отвечает и за выдачу статики и за обработку php скриптов. В итоге, при выдаче статики может получится ситуация когда ajax скрипты вылетают по таймауту. Сервер мощный, но ширина канала - узкое горлышко. Решено развести статику от динамики по разным серверам. Типа: xxx.com - статика, api.xxx.com - динамика. Вся проблема в том, что из-за кросс-доменного запроса не работают php сессии. Т.е. они работают, но каждый раз при запросе сервер посылает заголовок Set-Session с новой сессией. Делать ajax проксирование - не вижу смысла - будет тоже самое узкое горлышко но на сервере xxx.com, а не api.xxx.com. Есть какие-то варианты по разделению мух от котлет на разных каналах?

Comment: Или я чего-то не понял, или «каждый раз» в норме не бывает и что-то сломано конкретно у вас

Comment: так вроде, для выдачи статики есть прокси-сервер. Например, nginx

Comment: не внимательно прочитали поставленную задачу - не упростить жизнь сервера переложив статику на nginx, а разделить канал отдачи статики от канала выполнения динамики.

Насчет кросс-доменных запросов - я понял что CORS и сессии в принципе связать нет возможности, кроме каких-то диких планов по передаче сессий в открытом виде. Вот тут обсуждается именно такаяже проблема, но решения не предложено. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551402/cors-with-php-session

Comment: Не вижу проблемы, берете статику и хостите на серваке, крутите там `nginx`, бандлы ваших frontend приложений, допустим, на `static.domain.com`

Comment: Можете дальше развить мысль. Именно так сейчас и организовано. Один момент, который упустил в самом начале. На странице находится фрейм, с объемной(по весу) графикой и этим фреймом нужно управлять из главного окна и тут опять не получается фрейм вынести на отдельный хостинг, а основну. часть на отдельный - так как опять кроссдоменный запрос

Comment: Вы упомянули `кроме каких-то диких планов по передаче сессий в открытом виде` - я так понимаю это token авторизация, которая вам как раз подходит. Обычная сессия тоже вполне открыто передается из куки к серверу.